# Using Rails + Capistrano with Github and multiple branches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

In my Rails app, I'm using Git, GitHub, and Capistrano.  We have 2 servers (staging and production).

Up to now, I would make code changes on my local machine and push them to GitHub, then during deployment Capistrano would copy to either server from GitHub.

Now I have started using branches with Git. I created 2 branches locally on my machine, `dev` and `prod`. I'm the only developer at this point. I currently only have the branch master on GitHub.

Questions:

1) Should I create the `dev` and `prod` branches on the existing GitHub rpo or should I have a separate GitHub repo for staging and production?

2) If I do add branches, how would I tell Capistrano to use the `dev` branch for staging and the `prod` branch for production?

3) If using separate repos, how do I push a branch to the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use separate branches for development and production. I would make an 'experimental' branch.

A branch is really designed to be a safe place where you can break off of your `master` (your working code), and try something experimental. So really `master` **is** your production branch, and development is any branch you make off of that. When you've made your changes on your other branch, commit them, and then use

```
git checkout master

git merge newbranch
```

to merge the `newbranch` in to your master.

Comment: But, what happens when I make some changes in DEV, merge into local master, push to GITHUB, and deploy to staging server - then production server needs a hotfix?

Comment: Is the 'get' or 'git' merge?

Comment: It should be `git merge newbranch`

Comment: should be ` git merge` will edigt

Answer (score 0):

One repo is all you need.

Capistrano has a branch setting that controls the branch to deploy. I usually add

```
set :branch, ENV['BRANCH'] || 'master'
```

To my deploy.rb so that I can deploy different branches with

```
cap staging deploy BRANCH=some_branch
```

Personally I create a new branch for each release, so that it's very easy to deploy small fixes to production - I just cherry pick to the branch for that release and redeploy that branch.